# Android handler postDelayed executed twice

Tags: android, delay, handler

I'm trying to write a code that will be executed every 5sec, I read some about making delays and seemed that using postDelay method will help me to do this but for some reason this is executed twice. Every 5 seconds I get this Log, the difference is about 500ms. How can I modify this code to be done once every 5 seconds?

```
03-09 20:56:25.982 4735-4735/com.example.mdots_000.newprojectwithdelay I/Value: 1
03-09 20:56:26.442 4735-4735/com.example.mdots_000.newprojectwithdelay I/Value: 2

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    Handler handler;
    Runnable runnable;
    int delay = 5000;
    int value = 0;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        handler = new Handler();
    }

    @Override
    protected void onResume() {
        super.onResume();
        handler.postDelayed(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                runnable = this;
                value++;
                Log.i("Value", String.valueOf(value));

                handler.postDelayed(runnable, delay);
            }
        }, delay);

    }
}
```

Comment: you need to make sure onResume is called only once, window changes can reset it.

Comment: move your `handler.postDelayed(new Runnable() {` to onCreate